# Insomnia - HTTP POST method with request body having an integer

Tags: rest, http, insomnia

I'm doing a `POST` method on insomnia with the following payload

```
{
    “tag_ids”: [
        295
    ]
}
```

I'm receiving a status `400` bad request with the following error message

```
{
  "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 2 (char 3)"
}
```

When trying on `curl` I haven't had any issues and it is working as expected.
I'm wondering if it has something to do with the `tag_ids` being an integer in the request body, or if there is any settings I should change on the client for this to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your json contains `“` character instead of `"` for the property name.

This should be the correct body:

```
{
    "tag_ids": [
        295
    ]
}
```

Comment: @jetlibrucelee You're welcome, please accept it as the answer if that solves your problem :)